# How to limit date input and options to year-only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flatpickr

I'm using `Flatpickr` in my React component to select date input. Originally, it was supposed to be the full date, but I decided to change it to only include the year. This what I came up with:

```
class EducationForm extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  flatOptions = {
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: 'Y'
  }
  render () {
    <Flatpickr
      className='form-control'
      name='startDate'
      value={attributes.startDate}
      required='required'
      onChange={(_, str) => {
        this.updateAttribute(str, 'startDate')
      }}
      options={this.flatOptions}
    />
  }
}
```

While only the year is displayed when the input is not toggled, clicking it will still display the entire calendar month. How do I make sure it will only display year options for the user to pick?
[image]

Comment: As far as I can remember this is not possible in flatpickr. Their are no methods or config options that allow you to do so at the moment.

Comment: @mrdeadsven What other options do i have in react?

Comment: its better to use [react-year-month selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-year-month-selector) for selecting year only as it seems like Flatpickr doesn't provide year only selection.Its better to provide a input field with placeholder as there is only year to be selected

Comment: @Harikrishnan it uses jQuery instead of React.

Comment: @Bargain23 Hmm I never really used an only year picker in react but this one seems to be what you are looking for? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-year-picker. Ohh and if you want to switch back to a normal datepicker later on might want to check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-year. here you can just set the viewMode to years months or days.

Comment: You can use react-bootstrap-datepicker. 
all options are there.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-date-picker